# problems in git pull origin <branch name>

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I want to upload all modification in my bitbucket repository from my local system. **Process of upload all code on bitbucket repository**

```
git branch
git branch -a
git checkout <branch_name>
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin <branch_name>
git status
```

I have done above process for uploading code on bitbucket repository, and all modified file and code successfully uploaded in particular branch.
**But when fetched repository from a particular branch at server then some file is fetched and some file is missed (I used below proceess for fetching code from bitbucket repository)**

```
login in my server and go to project folder
git pull origin <branch_name>
then I got the following error => Error in app/controllers/index_controller.rb 
app/models/index.rb
app/views/index.html.erb
db/schema.rb
and so on
```

**then i followed these command**

```
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git reset file_path(app/controllers/index_controller.rb)
git pull origin +branch_name
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I followed all above process but I fetched some file from bitbucket repository and some file missed. **So please help me I tried 6 to 8 times but i got same problems, where am i wrong and what is mistake**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on which branch you are in. try first

```
git fetch --all
```

above will list all branches and then checkout on required branch, pull from there as normal.

Remember always make sure that pull /push is being done on same branches ie. if you are in master branch of local repo push same into master branch of bitbucket. In case you are sure that latest code is on bitbucket you can try 
    git pull -f origin

(-f is force to fetch from bitbucket to local)

Comment: I tried "git fetch --all" command then i got error: did you mean `--all` (with two dashes ?)

Comment: I tried also "git pull -f origin" then I got following message ( There are no candidates for merging among the refs that you just fetched.
Generally this means that you provided a wildcard refspec which had no
matches on the remote end. )

Comment: yes with two dashes, does fetch --all give all the remote list?